# PHP SimpleXML get document node

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I need to extract info from an xml document's outermost node (the document itself).  using the xml below:

```
﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<revue date="2015" issue="12345">
  <innernode>Oi</innernode>
</revue>
```

i would like to extract `2015` and `12345`.  i fail if i attempt to read the node `revue` using a foreach loop

```
foreach ($xml->revue as $revueIn) {
    foreach ($revueIn->attributes() as $z => $y) {
```

to see if i have typos or something, i inverted `innernode` and `revue`

```
﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<innernode>
  <revue date="2015" issue="12345">Oi</revue>
</innernode>
```

and above code worked (found the `revue` node and read its attributes correctly)

therefore, it seems to me that the outermost node is treated/perceived differently by SimpleXML.

does anyone know how to access the outermost node?  tks in advance 4 your time.

Comment: Try `foreach ($xml->attributes() as $z => $y)`

Comment: @MartinHonnen supply as answer, for it is correct and will be awarded as such.  SimpleXML does not access the document as a node (does it treat as a PARENT?).  Attribues are not node attributes, but document attributes and must be accessed directly, with `attributes()` and `getName()`

Comment: SimpleXML not see the root element in iteration. It shold be referenced by variable linked to SimpleXML object. So $xml node name will be 'revue'.

Comment: @splash58 precisely, it will be accessed via `getName()`.  i found the solution halfway thru writing the question, but figured that i should ask anyway, because someone is bound to run into the same issue.

Comment: @tonygil I meant exactly that as node name :)

Comment: @splash58 please post as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand it, the root element is simply your `xml` variable so to access its attributes you can simply use `foreach ($xml->attributes() as $z => $y)`.

Comment: Right you are!  Thanks 4 your time, i hope this helps others.

Answer (score 1):

`revue` is not the document node but an element node. It is the document element, actually.

If you load XML into a `SimpleXMLElement`, it will return the document element. You can use array syntax to access the attributes.

```
$element = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
var_dump((string)$element['date']);
```

Output:

```
string(4) "2015"
```

The attribute is returned as an `SimpleXMLElement`. You might need to cast it.

With `SimpleXMLElement::attributes()` you can access all attributes in a loop.

```
$element = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
foreach ($element->attributes() as $name => $value) {
  var_dump($name, (string)$value);
}
```

Output:

```
string(4) "date"
string(4) "2015"
string(5) "issue"
string(5) "12345"
```